# JPA/Hibernate Save 0000-00-00 Date in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date, null

I have the following problem:

I'm building a `Java`/`JSF`/`Hibernate`/`Spring` project over an existing old `FoxPro` System, sharing the same `MySQL Database 4.1`.

My problem is that the OLD system saves the NO DATE as 0000-00-00 instead of NULL.

So I solved the READING problem with `zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`, and works perfectly.

But, now I want to save some dates, and if I save NULL the old system may not work properly, so I want to save the 0000-00-00 while the old system is still in service.

What I tried and didn't work:

1. Changing the database using `NOT NULL` and `DEFAULT 0000-00-00` but
   still saving `NULL`.
2. Using a second date as String with @column annotation pointing to
   the same field of the database.  The `@column` that is a `Date` with
   (`insertable=false,updatable=false`) and the String with
   (`insertable=true,updatable=true`) still using the `java.util.Date`
   field.
3. `Mysql 4.1` doesn't have triggers I wanted to create one after
   insert null convert to 0000-00-00

So what I need is to save a `0000-00-00` when `java.util.Date` saves a `NULL` date, to keep both systems working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only solution that I found was to execute an update after inserting or updating, and change from NULL to 0000-00-00 Date. If I insert only one row I update that row with the ID, and if I update several rows I update like: set column_name='0000-00-00' where column_name is null